# Neovim on windows 10 - is it ready and how to set it up?

Tags: microsoft-windows, neovim

I am stuck on windows 10 and would like to give Neovim a shot. Is it ready, or should I just set up my vim configuration for the moment? I haven't really seen any videos or articles on Neovim under windows, but when googling, I found a few that lead me to believe there may have been issues that have not yet been adequately resolved.

Comment: One comment I have is that the only working binary I've found is from [build 658](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/equalsraf/neovim/build/658/job/notqv6akq02x45hw/artifacts)

Answer (score 11):

As stated on [neovim wiki](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#windows):

> Windows support is **(currently) experimental**. To try it out, you need nvim.exe and a front-end such as Neovim-Qt.

However there isn't a list of all features that are missing or unstable. The best way to discover is actually installing and trying.

Comment: I got nowhere with it. Hangs, small windows etc.  They've not updated the pre-built one for months. I've given up on it; I'll try again when they reach v1.  (I use it every day on various linux boxes without issue).

Comment: @DrEval Please see [my answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13800/622).

Comment: @Sardathrion I tried and that version has the same problem. White background I cannot shift no matter what i've tried.

Comment: @DrEval That happens from time to time when neovim-qt loses contact with neovim… But it should not happen often.

Comment: @Sardathrion It happens every single time and I have no way of configuring neovim-qt.

Comment: @DrEval You should report it as a bug then.

Answer (score 4):

Using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), you can install neovim like thus:

```
choco install neovim
```

Add `--pre` if you want the latest pre-release. It will install `nvim-qt` as well.

All in all, consider it *beta* software. However, it works well enough for my needs.

Comment: Optionally install using [`scoop install neovim`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#scoop), also don't forget to install python3 support by installing `pynvim`. It can be done by installing python3 through `scoop install python` and then `python -m pip install pynvim`

Answer (score 3):

One way to run NeoVim on Windows 10 is through "bash on windows". After setting up ubuntu on bash on windows, you can just install NeoVim the same way you would on a Ubuntu machine (add the PPA, etc.).

You will need at least Windows Insider Preview Build 14366 and NeoVim 0.1.5-dev (prior to this build it would crash).

You might wish to wait until the proper release of the Windows 10 anniversary update, though.

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4507

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13390779-neovim-crashes-on-bash-on-windows

Comment: As of 2017-02-24, this is working well for me. I had problems using terminal ConEmu (getting 256 colors working is a hassle, and doing so seemed to break cursor keys etc - they would in Bash but not in nvim. So I switched to wsl-terminal (https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal) which is less fully featured, but all the above just works out of the box.

Comment: Actually, one problem I still have with this set up is that it's easy to paste INTO Neovim, but I haven't yet figured out how to cut/copy text out of it. I have xsel installed, but neovim CheckHealth says "no clipboard tool found". I'm resorting to catting the file in a terminal and selecting it there to copy. Dreading the day when my Windows-oriented colleagues see me doing it. :-)

Comment: @JonathanHartley at my day job I'm now on a Mac, but this looks relevant: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3147 best of luck, I know what it's like stuck on windows :(

Comment: Thanks. I read that clipboard between Windows and WSL can be fixed by getting XMing running (A Windows port of X-Windows, I think, which is *much* easier to get running than you'd expect) and then clipboard management programs like xsel or xclip work just fine. https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1069#issuecomment-245793843